# Display 2 images per row side by side, centered horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

Let's say that I would like to display 4 images in my webpage like this:

```
img1 img2

img3 img4
```

I want every image to take 50% of the width of the webpage, but if its width is less than 50%, to be centered to this space (so I need it to be centered to the 50% of the left width).

Similarly, I want the image with the less height to be centered relatively to the height of the image on its side.

Example:

[image: example]

What I've tried till now:

HTML:

```
<div class="imgGroup">
    <div class="groupImg">
        <img src="images/speed.png" alt="Wind Speed Graph">
    </div>
    <div class="groupImg">
        <div class="strongCenter">
            <img src="images/wind_now.png" alt="Wind Direction Now">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.groupImg img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I've grouped the images 2-2 in `imgGroup` with the thought that I have to work with the height of the div in order to center the images inside.

Comment: Are you using `imgGroup` to create 'rows'.  So the image 3 and 4 can be in another `imgGroup` div?

Comment: @davidpauljunior True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML->**

```
<div class="imgGroup">
    <div class="groupImg">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZUUq4g.jpg" width="" height="150" alt="Wind Speed Graph" />
    </div>
    <div class="groupImg">
        <div class="strongCenter">
            <img src="http://bit.ly/1apzyBy" width="" height="100" alt="Wind Direction Now" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS->**

```
.imgGroup {
    background:Silver;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.groupImg{
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.groupImg img {
    background: White;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: block;
}

.strongCenter img{
    width: 50% !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This completely messes up the images. Please try your code with 2 images with Width1+Width2>Monitor Width and with another 2 images, with one rather large and one tiny. The tiny should be at the middle of the 50% of the screen width that is left and at the 50% of the height of the image, like in the example.

Comment: @user29781509 See why it fails: http://jsfiddle.net/99scm/3/  The cat's image shouldn't be stretched, but centered to the 50% space on the right of the image of the dancer, as in my example. The max-width of the images must be 50%, not the width to be 100%