# Showing search engine result horizontally using css in html

Tags: html, css, sql, search

I have created a search engine for my website and it is successfully importing the data. But the searched images are appearing vertically and I want them to appear two images per row. Below are my code and image of search results.

[image]

```
 <?php

 $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", " " , "grand_database");

 if($connection -> connect_error){

     die("Connection Failed : ". $connection-> connect_error );
 }

if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $keyword = $_GET['keyword']; 

        $min_length = 3;

            global $i;


            if(strlen($keyword) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

    $keyword = htmlspecialchars($keyword);

            $explosion = explode(" " , $keyword);

            $query = "SELECT title , link , image , description FROM search WHERE " ;

                foreach($explosion as $exploded_keyword){

                    $i++;

                    if($i == 1)

                        $query.= "keywords LIKE '%$exploded_keyword%' " ;

                    else
                        $query.= "OR keywords LIKE '%$exploded_keyword%' ";

                }

         $result = $connection -> query($query);

      if($result -> num_rows > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        echo "<div class = 'container'>

                <h3>You Searched For: $keyword</h3><br><h4>If you are not getting the desired results, please check your spellings or try different Search.

                </div>";

        echo '<hr>';

         while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){

                $title = $row['title'];
                $link = $row['link'];
                $image = $row['image'];
                $description = $row['description'];


                echo "<div class= 'container'> 

                <div class= 'row'>

    <div class= 'col-sm-4'>

        <img src= '$image' class= 'img-responsive thumbnail' style= 'width: 300px;'/>

        <h4><a href= '$link' target= '_blank'>$title<br></a></h4>
        <h5>$description</h5><hr>

    </div> </div> </div> <div class= 'container' style= 'height: 100px;'></div>";
         }


    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "<div class= 'container'><h3>No Results Found</h3><br><h4>Plese check your spellings or try different keyword</h4></div>";
    }

}
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "<div class= 'container'><h3>No result found!</h3><br><h3>Minimum length is $min_length<h3><br>

            <h3>Please enter the keyword, more than 3 characters.
        </div>";
    }

}

$connection-> close();
```

?>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display 2 images per row side by side, centered horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318152/display-2-images-per-row-side-by-side-centered-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: This is not a PHP question, this is a CSS question. Look into floats.

Comment: This is not the same question as above. My question is that how would I make my search results appear horizontally. Coding is written in PHP.

Comment: For better answers, take PHP out of your question. Flatten that into plain HTML so that others can copy/paste it to examine what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put more result in the same row. following code may serve your purpose.

```
for($l=0; $l<=count($result); $l+=3){
            echo "<div class= 'container'> 

            <div class= 'row'>
            $j=0;

  while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc() && $j<3){
            $j++;

            $title = $row['title'];
            $link = $row['link'];
            $image = $row['image'];
            $description = $row['description'];


            echo "<div class= 'container'> 

            <div class= 'row'>

<div class= 'col-sm-4'>

    <img src= '$image' class= 'img-responsive thumbnail' style= 'width: 300px;'/>

    <h4><a href= '$link' target= '_blank'>$title<br></a></h4>
    <h5>$description</h5><hr>

</div> </div> </div> <div class= 'container' style= 'height: 100px;'></div>";
     }}
```

main idea is to loop through result and place multiple in a same row. Hope that solves your issue

Comment: Thank you, sir, for the reply. But can you tell me where to place this code and how? Because I am getting errors.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Boehub\search.php on line 240. I think I have placed the code wrongly. can you please tell me where to place the code in my existing code.

Comment: It should come after the horizontal line of yours

Comment: I did everything, sir. but not getting any success. please help me.